# Import a BACPAC file into Azure to create a new database, but database-level user seems not imported correctly?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Here are my steps:

Step #1. Create a contained user in my SQL Server 2019 database

Step #2. Use this database-level user to connect to “Partially contained database” in my SQL Server. Yes, it works

Step #3. Export this SQL Server 2019 database to a `.bacpac` file, and import it into Azure database via Azure Portal

Step #4. Use this database-level user to connect to Azure database, no luck. But if I logged in as SA to Azure, I can see this user.

Step #5. Drop this user and recreate it in Azure database. All good. I could connect.

I was expecting that step #4 would work. Not sure why it failed. I googled some but could not find answers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export and import the .bacpac file to create the new database in Azure SQL database, it's a database migration.

The limit is that We must create the login/user manually.

We can not database-level user to connect to Azure database directly, we must enable the login and user first.

- To improve security, SQL Server Authentication logins are stored in a
  DAC export file without a password. When the file is imported, the
  login is created as a disabled login with a generated password. **To
  enable the logins, sign in using a login that has ALTER ANY LOGIN
  permission and use ALTER LOGIN to enable the login and assign a new
  password that can be communicated to the user.** This is not needed for
  Windows Authentication logins because their passwords are not managed
  by SQL Server.

For more details, you could ref: [Import a BACPAC File to Create a New User Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-ver15#security)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer by @LeonYue, you can change the password for users that have no login (i.e. database-level SQL authentication) after import by connecting to the database as sysadmin and executing `ALTER USER <user-name> WITH PASSWORD='<user-password>';`.

Like on-prem contained database users, Azure SQL Database allows SQL authentication at the database level for users with a password (no associated login). However, the password is not exported/imported for security reasons.